# Override Woocommerce Payment Gateway Templates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have made a change to the eBay payment gateway file as I want to change the PayPal button text to say something else. I figured this was my best solution as I am not familiar with doing my own hooks/filters.

I have checked this amended template file works - it does. However, when I load this to my theme files it does not override.

I have tried:

1. main theme directory
2. theme/woocommerce/file
3. theme/woocommerce/includes/gateways/paypal/file

None of these work... can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there is no override solution to your question. But you can add a brand new payment gateway 
simply extending the `WC_Payment_Gateway` class, in other words by adding another payment gateway.

**Step 1**

You can duplicate the file:

```
plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/class-wc-gateway-paypal.php
```

in your directory theme, change its name for convenience and include it in functions.php:

```
/*  Custom gateway class */
require( get_template_directory() . '/path/to/class-wc-gateway-paypal-custom.php' );
```

**Step 2**

This file holds the `WC_Gateway_Paypal` class which extends `WC_Payment_Gateway`. You can edit this file for your customizations.

Remember to change the name of the extender class:

```
class WC_Gateway_Paypal_Custom extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
    public function __construct() {

        $this->id                = 'paypal';
        $this->icon              = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_paypal_icon', WC()->plugin_url() . '/assets/images/icons/paypal.png' );
        $this->has_fields        = false;
        // Change the text in the way you like it
        $this->order_button_text = __( 'Proceed to PayPal', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->liveurl           = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        $this->testurl           = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        $this->method_title      = __( 'PayPal', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->notify_url        = WC()->api_request_url( 'WC_Gateway_Paypal' );
    }

    //other payment gateway stuff
}
```

Give it a try, let us know if you get stuck! : )

**UPDATE** 06/13/2014

It's also useful to know that there's a filter that allows you to change the paypal image, so:

```
function paypal_checkout_icon() {
    // pls return the new logo/image URL here
    return 'http://www.url.to/your/new/logo.png'; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_icon', 'paypal_checkout_icon' );
```

Comment: Thank you iEmanuele. I am wondering if a filter would be an easier solution?

Comment: Glad to help you, it seems there is not filter to apply to modify the text button, but there's one for change the icon: `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_paypal_icon', WC()->plugin_url() . '/assets/images/icons/paypal.png' );`, I'm going to update the answer with a this filter.

Comment: Very helpful. However, I found that I had to keep the `WC_Gateway_Paypal` extender name as-is for it to work properly. If you know of something that needs to be changed please let me know.

Comment: Where did you find the filter?  I'm looking for the documentation so I can change the same in a different payment gateway.

Comment: @sparky take a look here:
/includes/gateways/paypal/class-wc-gateway-paypal.php

Comment: Thanks but there are no clues in there about which filter to use for other gateways.  I'm using a gateway purchased from WC and it's stored outside the WC folder as a stand-alone WP plugin.  Looking inside my gateway class, there are no filters used in there, although I can see the line that sets the icon.  Obviously, I don't want to change the source code as this will be overwritten on every update.